# send Contact picture in vCard using javascript

Tags: javascript, vcf-vcard

I was trying to save a contact as vcf with all the required information, but the photo is not displayed.
here is my code snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            // With helper methods
            var fooBar = vCard.create(vCard.Version.FOUR);
            fooBar.addFormattedname("Mr Foo Bar");
            fooBar.addEmail("foor@bar.com", vCard.Type.HOME);
            fooBar.addAddress("street", "code", "city", "country", vCard.Type.HOME);
            fooBar.addName("Example One");
            fooBar.addPhoto("Programming-Quotes.jpg");
            fooBar.addLogo("Programming-Quotes.jpg");
            var link = vCard.export(fooBar, "Foo Bar", false); 
            document.body.appendChild(link);
```

The addPhoto and addLogo are not working.
what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Could you include those helper methods to your code example?

As for my experience with manual VCF files coding and including images inside the best solution was to encode an image with base64 so it worked perfectly on Android and iPhone. When I tried to use a link to an external image somewhere on the internet, the image didn't work.

I also suggest you to make sure you really need the version 4 and not the previous one. I guess more devices support the 3.0 version so I use it.

If you familiar with Javascript you can look closely to those helper methods and make sure they work as it was intended. I had a bad experience with one VCF file generator: it was creating poor and outdated markup so it worked bad and unstable across platforms so I researched the syntax and different VCF versions deep inside and started to code contact files manually since it's not so hard.

Comment: can you explain with a code example please

Comment: `BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
PHOTO;TYPE=JPEG;ENCODING=b: /* Your base64 encoded image goes here instead of the comment */ 
END:VCARD

`
There's an empty string in the end of VCF file

Comment: When you'll be coding other properties of the VCF file be careful with semicolons, don't omit them, where they are required: in an address property, for instance, if you don't have a state or a postal index you type `;` for every absent value.

Comment: If you have commas in any value, you should escape them with a backslash like this: `ADR;TYPE=work:;;Evolve street\, house 64\, building 2;New York;;;USA`

Comment: I encoded my image but it's displaying as PHOTO:TYPE.....    I have : after PHOTO not ;

Comment: Try to paste your base64 image using my example if you do it manually now. There is `;` after PHOTO property.
You can look at the syntax in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard#Properties). Remember that we're talking about the 3.0 version syntax now. 
Maybe your library generates something using other version syntax. Show your output here omitting the base 64 encoded image code